# Android Bottom Nav Bar Customization

Tags: android, user-interface, menu, navigation-drawer, navigationbar

I'm trying to create something that's similar to this bottom navigation bar. I would really appreciate any help you can give me :

[image]

This is my menu xml code (bottom_navigation_main):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_1"
        android:title="Home"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_2"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_2"
        android:title="Free"
        android:textColor="@drawable/nav_bar_selector"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_3"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_food_white"
        android:title="Other"
        android:textColor="@drawable/ic_3"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_4"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_4"
        android:title="Other"
        android:textColor="@drawable/nav_bar_selector"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_5"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_5"
        android:title="Other"
        android:textColor="@drawable/nav_bar_selector"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

This is my main layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/fullyTransparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/rlLeftDrawer"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlContentHolder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            app:itemBackground="@color/fullyBlack"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/fullyWhite"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/fullyWhite"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. I successfully implemented the new bottom nav bar from Android but I'm having issues styling it.

It currently looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Have a look at android.support.design:itemBackground & android.support.design:itemIconTint. I don't think app:itemBackground and the others are the right way to go.

Comment: @DoronYakovlev-Golani Are you saying that this will help with keeping all the icons the same size? I don't want one icon to be larger than the others when it is selected

Comment: That helped with changing the color